# How to filter mongoose collection by Id node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

Let's say I have a simple mongoose schema like this

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String;
    age: String,
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I can easily find all User collections with `User.find({})`. But I want to find only specified collections by their _id. 
For example I have 10 user collections, and want to find only users according their Id in this dynamic array
`["5b66c0868278664f0d2f2fec","5b66c5a947eaed565b694efa"]`

so I am required to use `where` or `match`?

Comment: find and print just  _id?

Comment: not only _id, but also name and age (all fields)

Comment: so your dynamic array will be different for names, ages and ids

Comment: in my array there will be only dynamic ids, and I want to find users according to their id in that array

Answer (score 3):

did you try [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)?

```
User.find({_id : {$in : ["5b66c0868278664f0d2f2fec","5b66c5a947eaed565b694efa"]})
```

> The $in operator selects the documents where the value of a field
>   equals any value in the specified array. To specify an $in expression,
>   use the following prototype:

```
User.find({ _id: { $in: ["5b66577c2f05bf1eb07956e0" ,"5b66b1879526eb0444d047cb"] }})
    .then(users =>{
        console.log("user", users)
    })
```

Comment: it gives just an empty array as a result

Comment: I edited to show you an example that works for me. searching  by multiple Ids.

Comment: Make sure the ids actually are in the db. Maybe it didn't find them because they're not actually there.

Comment: it works like a charm, the mistake was I was getting wrong ids, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pass user id in postman parameter, then assign it to a variable then pass it to the function which is written for db activities. Then modal.findone(id);